# How to get a window specification from a wrapper?

Tags: pywinauto

I have a wrapper of an element which is not always enabled or visible so I want to wait for it.
To do it, I have to get the window specification of this wrapper in order to do:

```
window_specification.wait("exists enabled visible ready")
```

How to implement the following function?

```
window_specification = get_window_specification(wrapper)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not implemented natively in pywinauto. But it can be created like this:

```
spec = app.window(handle=wrapper.handle, top_level_only=False)
```

In next major release we're planning to add waiting for specific state in wrapper object. So finding wrappers and waiting for state will be different options.

In current version (pywinauto==0.6.8) there is one more way: `wait_until` and `wait_until_passes` functions from module `timings`. It adds flexible waiting for any condition.

Comment: In my environment wrapper.handle returns nothing. why?

Comment: According to pywinauto doc, handle = None and  get_active() Return a handle to the active window within the process. Should I use get_active() instead?

Comment: Maybe the wrapped element doesn't exist any more. Need to find it again if it was re-created on the app side.